# Why are both sqlite3 and sqlite3-ruby gems referenced in the Rails 3 Gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rubygems

I created a new Rails 3.0.9 project. Among other things in the `Gemfile`, it includes:

```
gem 'sqlite3'
# gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
```

I know that the second line shown is commented out by default, but why is it included and when should it used?

I read the [announcement](http://groups.google.com/group/sqlite3-ruby/browse_thread/thread/4a533d58151e3654) that:

> This announcement is to let you know that the sqlite3-ruby gem is being renamed to (drum roll please) "sqlite3".

Based on this announcement, I am guessing that the second line—referencing the `sqlite3-ruby` gem—is included for legacy purposes, but I am not certain as I'm a Ruby and Rails newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the announcement

> We will maintain backwards compatibility by releasing an empty "sqlite3-ruby" gem that depends on "sqlite3".

Therefore, using either one will *essentially* result in `sqlite3` being installed.  If it appears as `sqlite3-ruby` in your gemset go take a look at your `Gemfile.lock` and I'm sure it'll have a dependency `sqlite3`.

P.S. since you mentioned that you're a newbie, you might be wondering what I mean by "gemset".  Ruby Version Manager (RVM) is a must - you can [read all about in my blog post](http://blog.bsodmike.com/2011/04/19/rvm-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/).

Comment: RVM was one of the first things I installed as I wanted a Ruby equivalent to Python's virtualenv. I agree it's a must.